# Implement Own Vector Class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vectors

I am preparing for an interview and came to know about this question: implement a vector class in C++. I thought of how I would write it an interview and included the code below. The things I know I did not cover already are:
1) No use of templates for different data types
2) No use of iterators for iterating.
My point is I wanted to write a simple code and I want to know if that would be sufficient to crack the interview round or not?
Can you please go through the below code and point out the things that I must cover from an interview perspective. Thanks.

```
class Vector{
        int capacity;
        int sizet;
        int *arr;
    public:
        Vector():capacity(0),sizet(0),arr(new int){}
        Vector(int size):capacity(size),sizet(size),arr(new int[sizet]()){}
        Vector(const Vector &v){            //copy ctor 
                capacity = v.capacity;
                sizet = v.sizet;
                arr = new int[sizet];
            for(int i=0;i<sizet;i++)
                arr[i] = v.arr[i];

        }
        int &operator [](int index){            //overloading index[] operator
            return arr[index];
        }
        Vector &operator==(const Vector& v){        //overloading assignment operator
        if(this != v){
                capacity = v.capacity;
                sizet = v.sizet;
                arr = new int[sizet];
            for(int i=0;i<sizet;i++)
                arr[i] = v.arr[i];
            }
            return *this;
        }
        void push_back(int elem){
            if(sizet == capacity){
                if(capacity ==0)
                    capacity++;
                else
                    capacity = 2*capacity;
            }
            arr[sizet++]=elem;
        }
        void pop_back(){
            sizet--;
        }
        void insert(iterator it,int size=1,int val=0){

        }
        int size(){
            return sizet;
        }
        void resize(int n){
        if(sizet < n){                  //if increasing the size
            for(int i=sizet;i<n;i++)
                arr[sizet++]=0;
        }
        else                            //decreasing the size
            sizet = n;
        }
        int at(int index){
            return arr[index];
        }
        int front(){
            return arr[0];
        }
        int back(){
            return arr[sizet];
        }

        ~Vector(){              //dtor
        delete arr[];
        }
    };
```

Edit: Resolved the naming conflict as was suggested.

Comment: By tagging C++11, are you targeting C++11?

Comment: yes I must. Although, I cant figure out if there would be any change in my code if I use C++11 or C++ 14?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. Your `Vector::operator[]` return a `vector&`. Your `insert` is empty and uses an undefined type `iterator`. You have a data member and a member function sharing the same name `size`. Your destructor is `~vector` instead of `~Vector`. And there are a lot of compile errors left.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not state this in my statement. I did not compile the code.
I only described like how I would write it in an interview like in a pen and paper. And needed a help to know what else should I cover or missed?

Comment: Code Review reviews working code. Fix the errors, do some tests, and try your best to ensure that your code is working.

Comment: thanks for pointing about the size and destructor name conflict. Like I said, my intention was to write it as in a pen and paper type code. So, that's why the naming conflict must have occur. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: The official vector specification also demands that `std::out_of_range` is thrown if you try to use `at(...)` with an index greater than the vector's size. I see nothing like this in your code. This breaks the promises given by using that name.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Also `unsigned int` is more appropriate than `int`  for denoting size. If you're using int for size, you're wasting half of its capacity.

Comment: @Vogel612, I wanted people to not repeat the already provided suggestions, that's why I updated the code in the post itself. But I get your concern.
Question: When I update all the suggestions in my code, and I still like to have one review on that. Can I post the updated code in the answer section?

Comment: @MFCDev the case you are describing is suited to asking what we call a "follow-up question". So: no. An answer is not the place for a question :) You may want to link to your new question in this one to avoid users pointing out things you later fixed.

Comment: Worth a read: https://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/02/27/vector/index.html

Comment: @MartinYork WOW! That's a brilliant article. Thanks!!

Comment: @MFCDev There was a set of 4 articles about vectors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. You tagged [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), but your code does not look like C++11. You do not implement move construction and move assignment. You should implement them. Here's a sample implementation using the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543).

   ```
   friend void swap(Vector& a, Vector& b)
   {
       using std::swap;
       swap(a.capacity, b.capacity);
       swap(a.sizet, b.sizet);
       swap(a.arr, b.arr);
   }

   Vector(Vector&& v)
       :Vector{}
   {
       swap(*this, v);
   }

   Vector& operator=(Vector v)
   {
       swap(*this, v);
       return *this;
   }
   ```

   This way, you don't have to define a separate copy assignment operator.
2. Your default constructor sets `arr` to `new int`. This makes no sense and cannot be handled by the destructor. You should set `arr` to `nullptr`.
3. Use `++i`, not `i++`, in discarded-result expressions. See [Difference between `i++` and `++i` in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/484492).
4. Consider using standard algorithms instead of hand-crafted loops when plausible. For example:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < sizet; i++)
       arr[i] = v.arr[i];
   }
   ```

   Can be replaced by

   ```
   std::copy_n(v.arr, sizet, arr);
   ```

   You will need to `#include <algorithm>` for this to work.
5. Your copy constructor uses assignment instead of member initializer clauses. You should use member initializer clauses uniformly. Now your copy constructor should look like this:

   ```
   Vector(const Vector& v)
       :capacity{v.capacity},
        sizet{v.sizet},
        arr{new int[v.sizet]} // to avoid dependence on member declaration order
   {
       std::copy(v.arr, v.arr + sizet, arr);
   }
   ```
6. Where is the `const` overload for `operator[]`, `at`, `front`, and `back`?
7. Your `push_back` is incorrect. It does not allocate any memory. You will get an out-of-range error when `capacity` exceeds the actual capacity. Same applies to `resize`.
8. `size()` should be `const`.
9. Your `at` does the same job as `operator[]`. `at` should check for out-of-range errors and raise an exception if `index >= sizet`.
10. `front` and `back` should return a reference instead of a value.
11. The implementation of `back` is wrong. It should return `arr[sizet - 1]`.

Comment: I highly doubt that 3. is still a major concern for modern compilers. At least in the example I checked on godbolt ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/BAzLxF)), the generated assembly is the same for pre- and post-increment.

Comment: @AlexV "This is mainly only a problem when the variable being incremented is a user defined type with an overridden ++ operator. For primitive types (int, etc) there's no performance difference. But, it's worth sticking to the pre-increment operator as a guideline unless the post-increment operator is definitely what's required." — Scott Langham

Answer (score 12):

It's great that you provide a test program.  Although it doesn't yet test very much, running it under Valgrind uncovers a few wild accesses:

```
==17803== Invalid write of size 4
==17803==    at 0x109773: Vector::resize(int) (221707.cpp:68)
==17803==    by 0x10938A: main (221707.cpp:103)
==17803==  Address 0x4d74c94 is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17803==    at 0x483650F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17803==    by 0x109508: Vector::Vector(int) (221707.cpp:11)
==17803==    by 0x1091FE: main (221707.cpp:92)
==17803== 
==17803== Invalid read of size 4
==17803==    at 0x1093CE: main (221707.cpp:105)
==17803==  Address 0x4d74c98 is 4 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17803==    at 0x483650F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17803==    by 0x109508: Vector::Vector(int) (221707.cpp:11)
==17803==    by 0x1091FE: main (221707.cpp:92)
==17803== 
==17803== Invalid read of size 4
==17803==    at 0x1097FD: Vector::at(int) const (221707.cpp:77)
==17803==    by 0x109406: main (221707.cpp:106)
==17803==  Address 0x4d74ca8 is 20 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==17803==    at 0x483650F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17803==    by 0x109508: Vector::Vector(int) (221707.cpp:11)
==17803==    by 0x1091FE: main (221707.cpp:92)
==17803==
```

One of the problems is that `resize()` doesn't allocate new capacity when necessary.  In fact, there seems to be quite some confusion between size and capacity throughout the code; *size* should be the number of objects we're logically storing, and *capacity* is how many we *could* store before we need to re-allocate.

When we do re-allocate, I would expect to use standard algorithms (`std::move()`) to copy the elements from old to new storage; there's no need to hand-code a loop.

I'd advise against writing `using namespace` - that defeats the very benefits that namespaces were invented to give us.

Comment: Thanks. These are good suggestions too. I have not used move ctor or assignment operator ever before so I did not know it's usage.
One question: Do I need to have both move and copy constructor in the Vector class? As well as both move assignment and copy assignment operator?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have a defined assignment operator without the corresponding constructor - they are normally implemented as a pair.  You may find it easiest to implement the move constructor and assignment operator using a `swap()` member - most decent tutorials will demonstrate that, so I won't elaborate further.